# How to insert a jQuery string into the placeholder element on an HTML form

Tags: jquery, dom

This is a branch question from [Typewriter Effect with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325008/typewriter-effect-with-jquery)

http://jsbin.com/araget/5

I'd like to sequentially inject and clear each string from the array into the 'placeholder' element on an html form. The function currently writes and clears each string into an empty span element.

No experience with jQuery :/, any tips on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(element).attr('placeholder','Write text here');
```

to get value of `placeholder` attribute in jQuery

```
var placeholder_value = $(element).attr('placeholder');
```

---

**Better use** [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$(element).prop('placeholder','Write text here');
```

to get value of `placeholder` attribute in jQuery

```
var placeholder_value = $(element).prop('placeholder');
```

---

Commented by [Tats_innit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210059/tats-innit)

**Read**

- [How to support placeholder attribute in IE8 and 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020826/how-to-support-placeholder-tag-in-ie8-and-9)
- [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Just for OP: **Placeholder attribute and IE8 and 9 issue** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020826/how-to-support-placeholder-tag-in-ie8-and-9 ! Rest is saweeeeet yo! `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit added that to answer ty :)

Comment: Saweeet Homzzz! Chuck in `.prop` as well man! **Prop vs attr** : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr ; lets make OPs life fullfilled with information `:P`