# Typing effect: Word per Word

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been figuring out how to have a typing effect that is word per word instead of letter per letter. So far, all links I've searched are offering letter per letter typewriter effect.

https://macarthur.me/typeit/
https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/

Is this possible to achieve? Or have you done something similar?

Comment: yes, it's possible.

Comment: The question does not have a specific programming related problem for us to solve, hence it's off topic in stackoverflow. Please review [ask]

Comment: @Esko hm... i think the question was pretty clear, though definitely poorly phrased :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typewriter-Effect for HTML with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180457/typewriter-effect-for-html-with-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typewriter-Effect for HTML with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180457/typewriter-effect-for-html-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy.
Just register an interval, split your text, reverse the array and pop the last item. The one you append to the text-container then. Done.

JS

```
var myText = "Some text you want to be typed automagically..";
var myWords = myText.split(" ").reverse();

var ntrvl = setInterval(function() {
  addNextWord();
}, 150);

function addNextWord() {
  var nextWord = myWords.pop();
  if(nextWord !== undefined) {
      var textNow = $(".write-here").text() + " " + nextWord;
      $(".write-here").text(textNow);
  }
}
```

What do you think of this?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muy58gwp/)

Comment: Thank you so much! :) They say it's not a programing specific to be solved... yet you still helped! I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Woppi you even improved the code, that's nice. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

create an array with whichever words you want to print one at a time.

```
const sentence = 'this sentence will be displayed one word at a time';
var arrayOfWords = sentence.split(' ');

for (var i = sentence.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(sentence[i]); // or display another way
    }, 400) // set this to your desired interval
}
```

Comment: You could also create a string and let the function split it..

Comment: @PatrickMlr yeah, you're right. using the split method would make it a lot more convenient instead of breaking apart the input manually