# Yoshi's jQuery typewriter effect break loop

Tags: jquery

I'm still very new to jQuery. I found this typewrite effect by [Yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697154/yoshi) and love it!!! Can someone please tell me, how to make it stop/freeze on the last line?

Here's the script: 
http://jsbin.com/araget/459/

Here's the question Yoshi answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13325547

I do apologize if I've posted this incorrectly, I just couldn't find another way to ask the question and I'm stuck :/

Comment: Huh? Taken this excellent given [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13325571/3509874), just remove the function from line 33 to 46.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `clearTimeout` if the length is equal to `text-index`

```
var clr=null;// variable for clearing timeout
.....
clr = setTimeout(function () { // 
    if(idx==settings.text.length-1){ // check if the length is equal to text.length-1
        clearTimeout(clr); // clear timeout
        return false;  // break the loop     
    }
    ....
    ....
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/araget/462/)**