# Wait for Javascript function finished inside foreach cshtml?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to make simple autotype with Javascript. My problem is the autotype is cannot run sequentially if i call it from view (.cshtml).

My cshtml like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/autotype.js")"></script>

@foreach (var temp in @Model)
{
    <script>
        auto_type("ABCDEFG", 0)
    </script>
}

<div id="divauto"></div>
```

and it's autotype.js :

```
function auto_type(wrt, i) {

    wrt = wrt.split('');
    var delay = 100;
    while (i < wrt.length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#divauto').append(wrt.shift())
        }, delay * i)
        i++;
    }
}
```

From these codes, the output will be like "AAABBBCCCDDDEEEFFFGGG" but i need the output like: "ABCDEFGABCDEFGABCDEFG"

Comment: The output is "ABCDEFG", not "AAABBBCCC...".

Comment: I get this `AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDDEEEEE` in my repro.

Comment: I would really question if you need to use Razor to output script in a loop like this. It's almost always better to leave script for client-side behavior, and use Razor for server-side behavior. You can certain use Razor to provide data for your client-side code to act upon, but trying to mix the two like this is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [jQuery deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).  In this case I had to use two recursive functions since you need flow control for both the iteration through the viewItems list as well as for kicking off `setInterval()` to update `#divAuto` for each character.

As an example of how promises are used here to add control, in `autoType()` you get a promise returned from the new `autoTypeUtil()`.  When the promise is resolved within `autoTypeUtil()` you call `autoType()` again with the remaining list.  This gives you flow control for the input items while still running asynchronously.

You may check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmf5a0az/15/) for a working example.

```
function timeString(arr, timeFactor, deferred) {
    if (arr.length === 0) { deferred.resolve(); }

    var ch = arr.shift();
    var deferredInternal = new $.Deferred();
    var promise = deferredInternal.promise();
    var delay = 100;

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#divauto').append(ch);
        deferredInternal.resolve("done");
    }, delay * timeFactor)

    promise.done(function() { 
        timeString(arr, timeFactor, deferred); 
    });
}

function autoTypeUtil(inputString, timeFactor) {
    var deferredTimeString = new $.Deferred();
    var deferredInternal = new $.Deferred();
    var promiseTimeString = deferredTimeString.promise();

    inputString = inputString.split('');
    timeString(inputString, timeFactor, deferredTimeString);

    promiseTimeString.then(function() {
        deferredInternal.resolve()
    });
    return deferredInternal.promise();
}

function autoType(arr, timeFactor) {
    if (arr.length === 0) { return; }

    var promise = autoTypeUtil(arr.shift(), timeFactor);

    promise.done(function() {
        autoType(arr, timeFactor);
    });
}

var viewItems = ["I", "love", "jQuery", "promises"];
autoType(viewItems, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a typewriter, or teletype effect, where the text is written out like a typewriter?

In that case, check out this SO question, as it looks like it will provide what you need.

[Typewriter Effect with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325008/typewriter-effect-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `i` is getting set to 7 at the end of your loop, which occurs before the first instance of it being called. Try something like this:

```
function auto_type(wrt) {
    wrt = wrt.split('');
    if (wrt.length > 0) {
        var delay = 100;
        type_loop(wrt, delay);    
    }
}

function type_loop(wrt, delay) {
    var myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);
        $('#divauto').text($('#divauto').text() + wrt.shift());
        if (wrt.length > 0) {
            type_loop(wrt, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    auto_type("ABCDEFG", 0);
});
```

This method is called [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) in case you're curious.