# Typewriter and setting duration time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, string

I want to a typewriter effect in HTML/JavaScript/jQuery, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325008/typewriter-effect-with-jquery), but I need to specify the duration total of the animation. For example if I set 10 seconds and the string is "dog" the animation will be very slow. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna use the same functions as in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325008/typewriter-effect-with-jquery).

It's really simple.

On line `typeString($tar, settings.text[idx], 0, settings.delay, function () {` and on line `deleteString($tar, settings.delay, function () {` change `settings.delay` for `(settings.delay / settings.text[idx].length)` then when calling the construction function pass the delay (in ms) option with the time you want. e.g:

```
    $('#target').teletype({
      delay: 10000,
      text: [
        'dog',
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,',
        'sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore',
        'magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et',
        'accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd',
        'gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor         sit',
        'amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,',
        'sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore',
        'magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et         accusam',
        'et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,',
        'no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'
      ]
    });`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could modify that existing plugin to add a new function that accepts a param for `totalDelay`, and then uses the existing `typeString` function with `delay` = `totalDelay / str.length`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!